# Want to use index.aspx instead of default.aspx in ASP.NET webapp

Tags: asp.net

I want to display index.aspx instead of default.aspx in the root of folders in my ASP.NET app but can't figure out where to set this.

Answer (score 4):

This is a change that you need to make in IIS. Please see [Setting Up Default Documents](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true) for how to do this:

> You can establish a default document
>   for client requests to a Web site that
>   does not specify a document name.
>   Default documents can be a directory's
>   home page or an index page.

Comment: Starting with IIS7, you can actually configure the default document in your web.config file (within the system.webServer element) as well.

Answer (score 2):

It should be called "Default Document" in your IIS setting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it in IIS 6 http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Manager, right-click the web site and choose properties, click the 'Documents' tab, and add index.aspx to the list.